# Downgrade alfersco 6.2(with governance service 6.2) to alfresco 5.2(with record management 2.7 b)

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, downgrade

Can we downgrade alfersco 6.2(with governance service 6.2) to alfresco 5.2(with record management 2.7 b)?
I tried but getting this error

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 07200018 
Downgrading of modules is not supported.
Module 'org_alfresco_module_rm' version 3.0 is currently installed and must be uninstalled before version 2.7 can be installed.
    at org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException.create(AlfrescoRuntimeException.java:52)
    at org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper.startModule(ModuleComponentHelper.java:633)
    at org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper.access$5(ModuleComponentHelper.java:530)
    at org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper$1$1.execute(ModuleComponentHelper.java:263)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:352)
    at org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper$1.doWork(ModuleComponentHelper.java:284)
    ... 45 more
2020-08-20 11:26:01,248 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiEngineInitializer.onShutdown(ActivitiEngineInitializer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:67)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If anybody knows how to do that can you please help whether it is possible or not to downgrade?

Comment: Generally, but not always, Alfresco only supports upgrades not downgrades. Are you using Alfresco Enterprise or Community?

Comment: Alfresco Community 6.2

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. First, you have one or more AMPs which you are trying to downgrade. In the log you are showing the RM AMP. Maybe you have others, I cannot tell.

Once a newer version of an AMP is installed you cannot downgrade it. You must first uninstall it using the MMT. Sometimes, this is enough. Other times, you must actually go into the System Store, find the module, and delete it.

Once you get rid of the newer AMP and you've started up the server successfully, you can shut down and install the older AMP.

Now we get to the second problem, which is that you are attempting to downgrade the repository. If the schemas match in the versions you are downgrading from and to, this might work. If the schemas do not match, I doubt it will work without you writing some scripts to essentially backout the schema changes that the upgrade did.

There is a list of schemas by Alfresco release [here](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-hub/release-cross-reference/ba-p/291343).